# Why does the array get overwritten?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a bug in my code and it appears that the array went strange after the `scanf()` loop for some reason.
What could be the reason here?

The inputs I entered were "a", "b", "c".
Here is the output from console:

```
all element are: a
all element are: b
all element are: c
s: c
after loop1: c
after loop3: c
```

`s_arr` changes after the loop is done.

This is my code:

```
int main() {

    char s[5];
    char *s_arr[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        scanf("%s\n", s);
        s_arr[i] = s;
        printf("all element are: %s\n", s_arr[i]);
    }
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
    printf("after loop1: %s\n", s_arr[0]);
    printf("after loop3: %s\n", s_arr[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s_arr[i] = s` does **not** make a copy of the string. If you `printf("%p\n", s_arr[i])` you'll find that all of the pointers in `s_arr` point to the same address, which is the address of `s`.

Comment: There is only one string in your program `char s[5]`. You have 3 pointers to strings, also. But they end up pointing to the same string.

Comment: Did this even compile **without warnings**?

Comment: `scanf("%s\n", s);` is very bad code. The `\n` in the format string makes for counterintuitive behavior (confusing users), and the lack of return value checking means you don't know whether `scanf` actually managed to read anything. Plus there's no input limit so you have a buffer overflow bug there.

Comment: What do you mean, the array went strange after the loop? There is no difference between the variables inside the loop and outside. The output is consistent with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't overwriting the array elements. However, each element is a pointer, and you are making each of `s_arr[0]`, `s_arr[1]`, and `s_arr[2]` all point to the string in `s`.

Since there is only one string, and each pointer points to that same string after the loop, you get identical results when you print them out.

One way to fix this would be to make `s_arr` an array of strings (i.e., a two-dimensional `char` array), and copy `s` into each one.

Also, consider `fgets()` for string input, so you can prevent buffer overflows.